# JSON as input in a mapreduce

Tags: json, r, hadoop, rhadoop

I have a JSON file contains fields such as machine_id, category, and ... Category contains states of machines such as "alarm", "failure". I simply like to see how many times each machine_id has been reported using **rmr2**. 
For example, if I have the following:

```
machine_id, state
48, alarm
39, failure
48, utilization
```

I like to see this result:

```
48,2
39,1
```

What I did:
I wrote a simple mapreduce to read the value of JSON file and used it as an input in the second mapreduce. Code is:

```
mp = function(k,v){
machine_id=v$machine_id
keyval(machine_id,1) }
rd = function(k,v) keyval(k,length(v))
mapreduce(input = mapreduce(input='\user\cloudera\sample.json', input.format="json" , map=function(k,v) keyval(k,v)) , map=mp, reduce = rd)
```

Unfortunately, it returns only the last two values of JSON file. It seems that it doesn't read entire of the value of the JSON file. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: have you tried to read in the JSON file directly using `jsonlite::fromJSON("sample.json")`

Comment: No, I didn't try it. But my original file is over 10GB and I am interested in using MapReduce.

Comment: ah - so this isn't an `r` question?

Comment: It is written in R by RMR2 package using Hadoop in Cloudera.